# IntelliJ Python Debugging with Blaze

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel

I'm currently trying to transition a project to Bazel, but I'm running into problems running the debugger for Python in IntelliJ. I have the current version of the Bazel plugin (v2019.06.17.0.1), and am using the current Bazel version (0.28.0). When I attempt to run a test in debug, I see

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 "/path/redacted" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 53571 --file /path/also/redacted
pydev debugger: process 24526 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build #.#.#.#)

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)
```

Has anyone found a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it with bazel plugin disabled?

Comment: The goal is to debug the code as it is built by bazel. If I disable bazel plugin, that won't be possible.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is caused by the plugin itself. So it's likely to be a 3rd party problem.

Comment: @SergeyK. You're right that it's the plugin, but the plugin is official from the bazel team. https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij